# Roll over effect

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi I have used a tutorial I found online to help me make a fading image 
when the user hovers over it.. I have tried to put a heading over this 
image but now run into a problem that means when the user hovers over the
 heading on top of it, the image fades out again.. what I really want to get it
 to do is have the whole thing fade into colour on hover..

Here it is on JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xxfairydragonxx/RpcRe/

if anybody can see a way of doing this i will be so greatful!

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="part2">
    <div class="fadehover">
    <div class="center">
        <h4>Independant Living</h4>
    </div><a href="#"><img alt="" class="a" src=
    "http://coffeemachines4u.co.uk/HarmonyHomes/Images/IndependantLiving.jpg"></a>
    <img alt="Harmony Homes Transitions" class="b" src=
    "http://coffeemachines4u.co.uk/HarmonyHomes/Images/IndependantLivingColor.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("img.a").hover(

    function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            "opacity": "0"
        }, "slow");
    },

    function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            "opacity": "1"
        }, "slow");
    });

});
```

Comment: The best way is to move the heading into the anchor so when you hover over that block, the image fades in or you can move the hover function to fadeover class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your `hover` event to the entire `.fadehover` element (which contains the title *and* the image), then target the image inside with your fade:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".fadehover").hover(

    function () {
        $('img.a',this).stop().animate({
            "opacity": "0"
        }, "slow");
    },

    function () {
        $('img.a',this).stop().animate({
            "opacity": "1"
        }, "slow");
    });

});
```

You also need to clean up your HTML a bit:

```
<div id="part2">
    <div class="fadehover">
        <div class="center">
             <h4>Independent Living</h4>
        </div>

        <a href="#"><img 
           src="http://coffeemachines4u.co.uk/HarmonyHomes/Images/IndependantLiving.jpg" 
               alt="" class="a"><img 
           src="http://coffeemachines4u.co.uk/HarmonyHomes/Images/IndependantLivingColor.jpg" 
               alt="Harmony Homes Transitions" class="b"></a>
    </div> <!-- .fadehover -->
</div> <!-- #part2 -->
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/eE5MC/

(Or, if you're keen on learning semantic HTML, use [`figure` and `figcaption`](http://html5doctor.com/the-figure-figcaption-elements/): http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/eE5MC/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand well what are trying to do:

You can add:

```
 $(".center").hover(
function() {
$('img.a').stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
},
function() {
$('img.a').stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RpcRe/1/)

Comment: this is inefficient since you need to bind on 2 elements instead of 1

Answer (score 0):

Put the hover effect on fadecenter

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fadehover").hover( function() {
        $(this).find('img.a').stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
    },
    function() {
        $(this).find('img.a').stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RpcRe/4/

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to put each block in a container instead

And have the container trigger it

```
<div class="imgblock">
img_block_here
</div>
```

...jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".imgblock").hover(
function() {
$("img.a").stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
},
function() {
$("img.a").stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
});

});
```

See the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RpcRe/2/